# Place title of multiplot panel with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

From the help found here I've managed to create this multiplot panel:
[image]
with the following code:

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

datos=read.csv("paterna.dat",sep=";",header=T,na.strings="-99.9")

datos$dia=as.POSIXct(datos[,1], format="%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

datos$Precipitación[is.na(datos$Precipitación)]=0
xlim = as.POSIXct(c("2010-05-12 00:00:00", "2010-05-12 23:50:00"))
ylim = trunc(max(datos$Precipitación) + 5)
tmax = trunc(max(datos$Temperatura) + 5)
tmin = trunc(min(datos$Temperatura) - 5)

tmx = max(datos$Temperatura) 
tmxpos=which.max(datos$Temperatura) 
tmn = min(datos$Temperatura) 
tmnpos=which.min(datos$Temperatura) 

tmp=ggplot(data=datos,aes(x=dia, y=Temperatura)) + geom_line(colour="red") + ylab("Temperatura (ºC)") + 
xlab(" ") + scale_x_datetime(limits=xlim ,format = "%H",major='hour') + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(tmin,tmax)) + geom_text(data=datos[tmxpos,], label=tmx, vjust=-1.5, colour="red") + geom_text(data=datos[tmnpos,], label=tmn, vjust=1.5, colour="blue")

pre=ggplot(data=datos,aes(x=dia, y=Precipitación)) + geom_bar(colour="blue",stat="identity",fill="blue") +
ylab("Precipitación (l)") + xlab("Hora solar") + scale_x_datetime(limits=xlim ,format = "%H",major='hour') + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,ylim))

vel=ggplot(data=datos,aes(x=dia, y=Velocidad)) + geom_line(colour="brown") + ylab("Velocidad (km/h)") + xlab(" ")  + scale_x_datetime(limits=xlim ,format = "%H",major='hour') + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100))

dir=ggplot(data=datos,aes(x=dia, y=Dirección)) + geom_line(colour="brown") + ylab("Dirección viento (grados)") + xlab(" ") + scale_x_datetime(limits=xlim ,format = "%H",major='hour') + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,360))

hum=ggplot(data=datos,aes(x=dia, y=Humedad.Relativa)) + geom_line(colour="blue") + ylab("Humedad relativa (%)") + xlab(" ") + scale_x_datetime(limits=xlim ,format = "%H",major='hour') + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100))

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(3, 2)))   
print(tmp, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1))         
print(vel, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2))
print(dir, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 2))
print(hum, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 1))
print(pre, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 3, layout.pos.col = 1:2))
```

Now I'm missing the title of the multiplot that I want to be the met. station name. I haven't found how to set main title on grid.newpage or viewport. I've read about grid.arrange but couldn't figure out how to use it in my case.

How can this be done? For sure it's gonna be an easy question for you.

You can find source data in http://ubuntuone.com/4G01ifn7cJ1jMIOKh

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**: Thanks to koshke I found the solution. The working code is:

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(4, 2, heights = unit(c(0.5, 5, 5, 5), "null"))))   
grid.text("MAIN TITLE", vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1:2))
print(tmp, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 1))         
print(vel, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 2))
print(dir, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 3, layout.pos.col = 2))
print(hum, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 3, layout.pos.col = 1))
print(pre, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 4, layout.pos.col = 1:2))
```

Comment: from [this document](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=push.viewport()%20title%20for&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstat.ethz.ch%2FR-manual%2FR-devel%2Flibrary%2Fgrid%2Fdoc%2Fviewports.pdf&ei=62b0TsOsD6ni4QTJwMmNCA&usg=AFQjCNHHdoDtfIENYhX4HsbkNArFtl91Yw&cad=rja) i found the command (last page but one) but I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for `grid.text("The user adds a title!", gp = gpar(fontsize = 20))`

Comment: @Seb, maybe it's possible to adapt. I think I have to name viewports and then look for the one I want to place the text in. Not sure if it's gonna work but will try. Thanks

Comment: the document linked describes how to get the viewport you're looking for - sorry that i can't be much of a help but i have no experience with this!

Comment: Tried but not completely working, it plots the title right in the center of the page maybe because there is only one viewport. It's promising so I have to go deeper in viewports. Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, probably you can use `+opts(title = XXX)`:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
p3 <- p2 + geom_line()

pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2)))  
print(p1 + opts(title = "bar"), 
  vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1))     
print(p2 + opts(title = "point"), 
  vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2))     
print(p3 + opts(title = "point and line"), 
  vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 1:2))
```

[image]

**UPDATED**

here is an example:

```
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(3, 2, heights = unit(c(1, 4, 4), "null"))))
grid.text("title of this panel", vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1:2))
print(p1, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 1))
print(p2, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 2))
print(p3, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 3, layout.pos.col = 1:2))
```

what you need to do is:

1. Make one extra row in grid.layout
2. Adjust width
3. Draw textGrob on the extra viewport row.

[image]

Comment: This is not what I need, maybe I didn't explain well. Data comes from a meteorological station, then I want to place the station name and date (a title) on top of the panel. I don't need a title in each graph (I removed them from my first try) as the y axis also names the graph. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I have updated. At the moment, layout for ggplot2 is not straightforward. Maybe it will be more easy in future.

Answer (score 28):

```
library(gridExtra)

p <- ggplot()

grid.arrange(p,p,p,p,p, top = "Title",
            layout_matrix = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,5), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain this a bit?

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/arrangeGrob#title-andor-annotations

Comment: @rawr, this link is dead I'm afraid

Comment: @DaveRGP I think [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html#title-andor-annotations) is it, [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/gtable.html) might also be useful. I'm not sure why baptiste's repo is gone from his github page

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can use the really helpful package [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com) to easily combine multiple plots in one graph. To add a main title to the multiple graphs, you can use [plot_annotation](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/annotation.html). Here is a reproducible example using the `mtcars` dataset:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +           
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("title 1")
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec)) +
  geom_density() +
  ggtitle("title 2")
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  ggtitle("title 3")
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, carb)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("title 4")

p_all <- (p1 + p2) / (p3 + p4) +    
  plot_annotation(title = "Main title of Multiplot") & 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p_all
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>