# ggplot multiplot - keeping the title at the bottom

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question is similar to the following post, the only thing I need is to place the titles of each subplot below each figure instead of on the top.

[Place title of multiplot panel with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615530/place-title-of-multiplot-panel-with-ggplot2)

Suggestion from baptiste working fine but, I have just two figures and I want them side by side.

```
p = qplot(1,1) 
lp = list(p,p)
ll = list("sub 1", "sub 2")
plotlist <- mapply(arrangeGrob, lp, sub=ll, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
do.call(grid.arrange, plotlist)
```

Thanks

Comment: do you mean one title for each individual plot, or one global title for the page?

Comment: `do.call(grid.arrange, c(plotlist, list(ncol=2)))`

Answer (score 4):

```
library(gridExtra)

p = qplot(1, 1)
grid.arrange(p, p, p, p, sub = textGrob("TITLE BELOW", gp=gpar(cex=2)))
```

[image: sub]

`ggplot2` does not have a "sub" parameter, so we wrap each plot in a gTree using `arrangeGrob`, combining the plot with a text label below. Finally, arrange the composite grobs on the page.

```
lp = list(p, p, p, p)
ll = list("sub 1", "sub 2", "sub 3", "sub 4")

plotlist <- mapply(arrangeGrob, lp, sub=ll, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
do.call(grid.arrange, plotlist)
```

[image: sub2]

Comment: My code is given below: I need the figure side-by-side not one below the other. lp = list(g1,g2)
ll = list("sub 1", "sub 2")
plotlist <- mapply(arrangeGrob, lp, sub=ll, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
do.call(grid.arrange, plotlist)

Comment: *please* provide a reproducible example and a clear description of your question