# R: Grid layout title

Tags: r

I'm using the grid package to display an array of plots like this:

```
layout <- grid.layout(2, 4)
pushViewport(viewport(layout = layout))
# print various plots
```

Is there some way to specify a title for the *whole* grid layout?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Dummy example based on a similar SO question: [Place title of multiplot panel with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615530/place-title-of-multiplot-panel-with-ggplot2)

1. First create a layout with the required number of rows + 1 short one for title:

   ```
   pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(3, 2, heights = unit(c(0.5, 5, 5), "null"))))
   ```
2. Create some plots there:

   ```
   print(ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp)) + geom_histogram(), vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 1:2))
   print(ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt)) + geom_histogram(), vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 3, layout.pos.col = 1))
   print(ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) + geom_histogram(), vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 3, layout.pos.col = 2))
   ```
3. Add a title to the top row:

   ```
   grid.text("MAIN TITLE", vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1:2))
   ```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: using a base plot is a little confusing; particularly since it doesn't respect the layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot @baptiste, I have updated my answer based on your guidance (and `+1` for your answer and great package).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the title scales with the graphs. However, I'd like the title to have constant height as the window is resized or when I print to PDF.

Comment: just set the layout heights accordingly, e.g. `unit.c(unit(1, "line"), unit(rep(0.5, 2), "npc") - 0.5*unit(1, "line"))`

Answer (score 20):

Another way:

```
library(gridExtra)
g = rectGrob() # dummy "plot"
grid.arrange(g, g, g, g, ncol=2, top = "Main Title")
```

Comment: Can you give an example that works with a somewhat formatted title? E.g. where the top parameter is not a text but a grob, how would that work?

Comment: `grid.arrange(g, g, g, g, ncol=2, top = textGrob("Main Title",rot=90))`