# Editing grid.table features

Tags: r

I'd like to plot a simple grid. Here and there I found that people use `grid.table`.

I have managed to display my data in the simplest way possible like so:

```
library("gridExtra")
cmSmall = 5
cmMed = 7
cmBig = 15

df = matrix(ncol=4,nrow=2)
df[1,] = c('Size',"small","medium","large")
df[2,] = c('cm',cmSmall, cmMed, cmBig)
df = as.data.frame(df)


grid.table(df, show.rownames=FALSE, show.colnames=FALSE)
```

[image: This is how it looks:]

Now, I would like the following:

1. Put 'Size' and 'cm' in bold
2. Add a title (with two rows) for this table (should I somehow add this to a plot?!)

Any idea how to do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: This can really help with item (2): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774703/adding-text-to-a-grid-table-plot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do 1 in a hacky way by moving that column to the row names, displaying it and modifying the styling of the rownames:

```
grid.table(`rownames<-`(df[-1],df[[1]]), gpar.rowtext = gpar(fontface = "bold"),
 gpar.rowfill = gpar(fill = "grey95", col = "white"), show.colnames=FALSE)
```

Comment: +1 This is probably the simplest way to proceed at this stage; getting **gridExtra** to work with the new **grid** functionality requires too much hacking for your typical[so] answer.

Comment: Thank you, James! This indeed solves item 1. Is there a simple way to add item 2? If gridExtra is the wrong way to go, I really don't mind trying something else... I am new to R and that's the first thing I found - might not be ideal...

Comment: Have a look at this question for the title: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10776139/269476

Answer (score 1):

*This is more an extended comment than a solution, but exists to explain why part **1** of the question is quite difficult at the moment*---

1 at least is actually very difficult and, as chance would have it, is discussed by Paul Murrell in the latest issue of the [R Journal](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-2/) ([PDF](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-2/murrell.pdf)).

The problem boils down to this:

```
R> grid.table(df, show.rownames=FALSE, show.colnames=FALSE)
R> grid.ls()
GRID.table.1
```

At this point, `grid.table()` has created a `table` grob, which only gets completed with grobs that form the actual table at *draw time*. This is achieved via an appropriate `drawDetails()` method for the. But until the table is actually drawn, there is no way to edit the individual grobs that are used to draw the table; they don't exist yet.

R versions >= 3.0.0 introduced some new functions and a new way of working that would allow what you want, but `grid.table()` would need to be changed to use the new functionality in the **grid** package. Effectively this would boil down to writing a `makeContent()` method for the `table` grob, which could then be forced using `grid.force()` to populate it with the individual grobs need to draw the table. At that point you'd be able to use `grid.edit()` to make "Size" and "cm" bold.