# How to add a title for a grid.layout figure in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using grid.layout() function to arrange a number of plots in one single figure. However, I do not know how to add a main title for the whole figure (at the mid-top of the figure)?

Does anybody know this and can help me out? Many thanks!

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776139/r-grid-layout-title

Comment: Yes, thanks very much!

Comment: I suggest this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10776757/6582929

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I personally like this solution provided by `cowplot` maintainers on [github](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/blob/master/vignettes/plot_annotations.Rmd):

Make two plots

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) + geom_point(colour = "blue") + background_grid(minor='none')
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) + geom_point(colour = "green") + background_grid(minor='none')
```

Use `cowplot::plot_grid` to combine the plots

```
p <- plot_grid(p1, p2, labels=c('A', 'B'))
```

Make a title

```
title <- ggdraw() + draw_label("MPG declines with displacement and horsepower", fontface='bold')
```

Add title

```
plot_grid(title, p, ncol=1, rel_heights=c(0.1, 1)) # rel_heights values control title margins
```